# Maven multi module project packaging error

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-3, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to develop multimodule project with maven. But when I want to package my project it gives errors.

It says package does not exist in web class. I already tried the solution on ask & answer part. But did not work.  Can you review my repo and tell me what I did wrong, please?

```
[INFO] 8 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] xguru .............................................. SUCCESS [  1.330 s]
[INFO] data ............................................... SUCCESS [  5.453 s]
[INFO] web ................................................ FAILURE [  0.746 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.064 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-04T12:15:14+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 48M/391M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project web: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asus/IdeaProjects/xguru/web/src/test/java/com/alikaan/xguru/controller/OwnerControllerTest.java:[3,31] package com.alikaan.xguru.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asus/IdeaProjects/xguru/web/src/test/java/com/alikaan/xguru/controller/OwnerControllerTest.java:[4,33] package com.alikaan.xguru.service does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asus/IdeaProjects/xguru/web/src/test/java/com/alikaan/xguru/controller/OwnerControllerTest.java:[32,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class OwnerService
[ERROR] location: class com.alikaan.xguru.controller.OwnerControllerTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asus/IdeaProjects/xguru/web/src/test/java/com/alikaan/xguru/controller/OwnerControllerTest.java:[37,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Owner
[ERROR] location: class com.alikaan.xguru.controller.OwnerControllerTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asus/IdeaProjects/xguru/web/src/test/java/com/alikaan/xguru/controller/OwnerControllerTest.java:[45,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Owner
[ERROR] location: class com.alikaan.xguru.controller.OwnerControllerTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asus/IdeaProjects/xguru/web/src/test/java/com/alikaan/xguru/controller/OwnerControllerTest.java:[45,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Owner
[ERROR] location: class com.alikaan.xguru.controller.OwnerControllerTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asus/IdeaProjects/xguru/web/src/test/java/com/alikaan/xguru/controller/OwnerControllerTest.java:[46,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Owner
[ERROR] location: class com.alikaan.xguru.controller.OwnerControllerTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/asus/IdeaProjects/xguru/web/src/test/java/com/alikaan/xguru/controller/OwnerControllerTest.java:[46,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Owner
[ERROR] location: class com.alikaan.xguru.controller.OwnerControllerTest
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :web

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And Here my pom.xml files:

PARENT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.alikaan</groupId>
    <artifactId>xguru</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>data</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <name>xguru</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <start-class>com.alikaan.xguru.XguruApplication</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <goals>install</goals>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

WEB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>xguru</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.alikaan</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>web</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alikaan</groupId>
            <artifactId>data</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--Required to get circleCI working-->
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

DATA:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>xguru</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.alikaan</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>data</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <!--Note your version numbe might be different-->
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What's the packaging type for `web` and `data` modules? From the `pom.xml` you posted, both projects have no packaging defined. I am not sure, but it looks like `data` should have a `<packaging>jar</packaging>´ tag, and `web` should have a `<packaging>war</packaging>` tag.

Comment: My packaging type  pom I have described in my parent pom

Comment: The child projects need to have their own packaging types defined. Your web module expects the data module as a jar library.

Comment: Unfortunately does't work

Comment: @VitorSantos modules will use the default `jar` packaging type

Comment: @VitorSantos Thanks. I had <packaging>war</packaging> in all my submodules. Changing it to jar solved the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figure it out by adding to data pom this

```
   <properties>
    <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
   </properties>
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem with the project structure. Since the parent artifact of your reactor parent is

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
```

all artifacts, including the `data` module artifact will execute this plugin execution:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>repackage</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The `data` module should not be repackaged to a fat jar, since you don't want to execute it as a Spring Boot application. You want to use it as a dependency artifact.

Don't use the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a reactor parent! Instead, import the Spring Boot BOM into your parent's `dependencyManagement` (more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Add this to the parent's `pluginManagement`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</plugin>
```

Move the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` invocation from your parent to the `web` module so only `web` will be repackaged, `data` will not be.

Finally, invoke `mvn clean install` from the parent directory. `install` is required for the reactor to work, since the dependency artifact (`data-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`) must be copied to the local Maven repository (usually `~/.m2/repositories/...`) before it can be used as a dependency by the `web` module.